# Why pump isn't blocked if you try to put unleaded gas into diesel car?

Tags: car

If you put unleaded gas into a diesel car, it will damage the engine considerably and you will have to change it . Considering the cost of replacing an engine PLUS the high probability of the event occurring since diesel and unleaded hoses are often adjacents : why the unleaded hose isn't blocked automatically if it reads *diesel car* on a simple RFID tag located on the car ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a home improvement question. Or even a FIY question, really. It's a question about industrial design.

Comment: can you indicate me the right forum to post this question ?

Comment: The answer is because that would require expensive and sensitive equipment, and because most people with diesel-powered vehicles are acutely aware of that fact, so this is rarely a problem.

Comment: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Murphy's Law will also need a very expensive sensor in all diesels to test for unleaded gas when someone fills the fuel station's diesel tank with gas.  Has happen a few times.

Comment: They already do.  The pipe is a different size so the nozzle will be all loosy goosey on a diesel car. It just requires the operator pay a little attention.  Most people pay enough attention to not accidentally pay 20 cents more for premium fuel; so they're already paying attention, just need to do it a tiny bit more.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases they are -- there are mis-fueling flaps that prevent insertion of incorrect nozzles into the car.

In general, diesel nozzles will not fit into unleaded gas nozzles due to being the wrong size.  There are attempts to keep unleaded gas from going into diesel nozzles with these flaps.
https://static.nhtsa.gov/odi/tsbs/2014/MC-10124720-9999.pdf